# Is `size_t` always an alias for `vector<int>::size_type` or any other container type?

Tags: c++, size-type

Let's make the simplest example possible:

**Formulation 1:**

```
std::vector<int> vec;
// add 10E11 elements
for(std::size_t n = 0; n < vec.size(); ++n)
    // ...
```

**Formulation 2:**

```
std::vector<int> vec;
// add 10E11 elements
for(std::vector<int>::size_type n = 0; n < vec.size(); ++n)
    // ...
```

Naturally, `unsigned int` or any inappropriate data types do not work here and we have to compile x64. My question is: Is there any case in which the first formulation can lead to issues or can we *safely* always write it in this much shorter notation? I would also be interesting in similar settings if they are trivial to cover (x86, any other container, other applications of `size_type`).

Comment: You wouldn't have the problem if you'd be using iterators and `auto`... ;-)

Comment: There are cases where I need to keep track of the index count or might change the iteration index in the loop

Comment: The typical definition is that size_t can store the maximum size of a theoretically possible object of any type (including array).

Comment: @IceFire: Index count is `it - vec.begin()`, changing the iterator is `it += x`. But that's just nitpicking, I see your point. I just hope you see mine as well. ;-)

Comment: an ugly hack to get the type right is `auto n = vec.size() * 0;`

Comment: @DevSolar I do! Question is whether we still have a performance benefit when using iterators but deducing the index count. I suspect, there is, but have not searched for benchmarks yet

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`std::vector` guarantees that pointers are valid iterators for its entire sequence, because `vector::data` returns "A pointer such that `[data(), data() + size())` is a valid range." That's pointer addition, which is defined over `std::ptrdiff_t`, which is the signed version of `std::size_t`.

Also, [iterator.requirements.general]/6 applies:

> … for integral values `n` and dereferenceable iterator values `a` and `(a + n)`, `*(a + n)` is equivalent to `*(addressof(*a) + n)`…

It's possible for `vector::size_type` to be *narrower* than `std::size_t`, for example 32 bits on a 64-bit system. But it's not something I'd worry about.

Comment: So, to be explicit about your finding: the standard implies that `sizeof(std::size_t) >= sizeof(std::vector<T>::size_type)` for any `T` and any allocator, so that `size_t` is always safe to use but might be inefficient memory-wise in some cases?

Comment: @IceFire Right. Actually `size_type` is unrelated to the allocator-aware interface and it would be surprising to see any dependency on the allocator. For any container, it's (at least) as wide as `make_unsigned_t<Container::iterator::difference_type>`.

Comment: … eh, actually not so surprising, it would just be fancy-pointer support. The catch is just that the standard is rather constraining on fancy pointers.

Answer (score 3):

Although it is the case in all common implementation, the standard makes no guarantee on this. What is guaranteed is that `std::vector<T>::size_type` is an implementation defined unsigned integer type.

References:

23.2.1 General container requirements [container.requirements.general]

> X::size_type [is a] unsigned
>   integer type

and 23.3.6.1 Class template vector overview [vector.overview] §2

> ```
> typedef implementation-defined size_type; // see 23.2
> ```

Answer (score 0):

While `std::vector::size_type` is usually `std::size_t`, there is no guarantee that it must. It's safer to use

```
for(std::vector<int>::size_type n = 0; n < vec.size(); ++n)
```