# How to printf std::vector<>::size_type?

Tags: c++, printf, c++14, std

`std::vector` has a member type `size_type`. What is its printf format specifier?

Note that `size_type` is not identical to `size_t`.
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/size_t
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf

Comment: How to find?   Read the documentation, use google, etc.    C++11 and later the `%z` format corresponds to `std::size_t`  (just as in C99 and later `%z` corresponds to `size_t`).    Strictly speaking, it is implementation-defined whether `std::vector::size_type` is the same as `std::size_t`, but I'm yet to encounter an implementation for which it isn't.  Before C++11 (and C99) it was necessary to convert to another integral type (like `long unsigned`) after checking the value is in range.   Practically, in C++, better to use C++ streams (which handle `size_t` correctly via function overloading)

Comment: One option is to cast to `uintmax_t` or `std::size_t` (not sure if it is big enough to hold `std::vector::size_type`).

Comment: @Peter Thank you for the information  and  suggesting workarounds.

Comment: @Peter It's `%zu`.

Comment: @Bob__ I changed the dupe target. It looks correct now.

Comment: @cigen The "dupe" does not even mention "std::vector<?>::size_type". Could you please remove it? I think KamilCuk gives a good answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What is its printf format specifier?

No one knows. It's not specified what `std::vector<?>::size_type` exactly is, except that it is a "unsigned integer type" int [C++ Container Library, General container requirements](http://eel.is/c++draft/container.requirements). Because `printf` format specifier depends on the type, it all depends on particular implementation. It may also be possible that there doesn't exists a `printf` format specifier.

> How to printf std::vector<>::size_type?

In steps:

1. Create a library to get `printf` formatting specifier depending on the type.
2. Template that library on that type.

It's just the same as `std::cout::operator<<` overloads are doing for printing anyway. Just:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>

template<typename T> constexpr const char *get_printf_formatting_spec() noexcept;
template<> constexpr const char *get_printf_formatting_spec<std::size_t>() noexcept {
    return "zu";
}
template<> constexpr const char *get_printf_formatting_spec<unsigned long long>() noexcept {
    return "llu";
}
/// etc.

int main() {
    const auto fmt = std::string() + 
        "%" +
        get_printf_formatting_spec<std::vector<int>::size_type>() +
        "\n";
    std::printf(fmt.c_str(), static_cast<std::vector<int>::size_type>(1));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The option to use in the `printf` is `%zu`.

This is used from C99. Before you need to cast the type to `unsigned long`.

Comment: Can you give a reference for this?

Comment: no, size_type is not necessarily the same as size_t: [Is `size_t` always an alias for `vector<int>::size_type` or any other container type?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41501798/995714), ['size_t' vs 'container::size_type'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/918567/995714)

Answer (score 1):

**A humble practical hack**

There seems to be no elegant, straightforward way to do this, as other answers suggest. What to do, then? For lack of a better approach, let's be humble and go back to basics:

1. Find printf format specifiers for the largest (size-wise) signed and unsigned integer types that you can.
2. At compile-time, determine the signedness of the vector `size_type` using `std::is_signed_t<T>`.
3. At run-time, check that the size value is small enough to fit into the target type, otherwise just declare failure.
4. Cast the `size_type` to the appropriate integer type.
5. You can now use the cast value in a printf call.

PS - To choose between the signed/unsigned format specifiers, you will need to either construct the format string dynamically, or choose between two format strings, or use conditional compilation etc. Instead, you could just go for the largest signed type and always cast into *that* - at the price of failing for the largest sizes which need that last bit.